# Unable to get these to cooperate: mysql-python + virtualenv + percona + centos6

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, mysql-python, centos6, percona

I've gone through many threads related to installing mysql-python in a virtualenv, including those specific to users of Percona. None have solved my problem thus far.

With Percona, it is normal to get a long error on `pip install MySQL-python` in the virtualenv that ultimately says `EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found`. One method to remedy this is `yum install mysql-devel`, which I've done. I can actually get mysql-python to install properly outside of the virtualenv via `yum`.

I'm getting the error in the virtualenv *only* - it uses Python 2.7.9, wheareas 2.6.6 is what comes with Centos.

Also, with MySQL-python installed via yum it will import to the OS's python interpreter, but will not import into the virtualenv's python interpreter.

To clarify, I only installed mysql-python via `yum` to see whether or not it would work that way. I would prefer it be by `pip`, in the environment only.

What am I missing here? As far as I'm aware it *should* work - considering it will work outside of virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! 
I think it was improper of my to install mysql-devel in the first place, so I went ahead and uninstalled it.

Instead, I used a packaged supplied by Percona - `Percona-Server-devel-55`

`yum install Percona-Server-devel-55` and the problem is solved!